# Contextual-Bandit Approach: Algorithm 1 LinUCB with disjoint linear models

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to implement the algorithm called LinUCB with disjoint linear models from this paper "A Contextual-Bandit Approach to Personalized News Article Recommendation" http://rob.schapire.net/papers/www10.pdf

This is the algorithm:
[Algorithm 1 LinUCB with disjoint linear models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRkmI.png)

I am confused about the features vector Xt,a (I highlighted on the algorithm). 
Is the feature vector related to information (context) of the article(arm) or the user?

I would appreciate your help.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature vector x_t,a applies to both the user and the arm.

> The vector xt,a summarizes information of both the user ut and arm a,
>   and will be referred to as the context.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

In the most general case, the feature vector *X_(t,a)* is allowed to be a *function* of both the user context *c_t* and the arm *a*, or *X_(t, a) = phi(c_t, a)*. Note that this could simply be a subset: each arm might have different features it uses to predict an outcome, or in other words *X_(t, a)* is a subset of *c_t*.

For example, if a movie recommendation website is deciding which movie to recommend, they might need different information from the user when attempting to predict if he'll like sci-fi movies versus drama movies. This different information is reflected in the fact that features are allowed to vary by arm.

Alternatively, it might be the case that *X_(t, a)* is the same for all *a*, i.e. *X_(t, a) = X_t*. For example, when trying to learn the best medical dosage, the algorithm might want to know height, weight, and age for all the patients. In this case the features would not vary by arm.